# get Records in given todate and fromdate in linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

i am having Following CliientDetails table

### **CliGenDate (varchar(50)  Cliname(varchar)

07/26/2013                a
07/25/2013                b
07/24/2013                c
07/23/2013                d
07/22/2013                e**

assume my todate(DateTime) is 07/22/2013 and fromDate(DateTime) is 07/24/2013

and **Result will be**

### **CliGenDate (varchar(50)  Cliname(varchar)

07/24/2013                c
07/23/2013                d
07/22/2013                e**

**i want Linq query**

i have tried Following code but gives an error msg

```
var Result = 
    (from a in Context.CliientDetails.AsEnumerable()
     where a.cliUserName == SalesEmail 
         && DateTime.Parse(a.cliGenDate)>=todate 
         && DateTime.Parse(a.cliGenDate)>=FromDate
     select new NewClientReg_BusinessLayer.Models.viewClientDetails
     {
        cliGenDate = a.cliGenDate,
        cliAckNo = a.cliAckNo,
        cliFullName = a.cliFullName,
        cliTopic = a.cliTopic,
        cliCourse = a.cliCourse,
        cliDomain = a.cliDomain,
        cliTotalInvest = a.cliTotalInvest
    });
```

but it gives Following Error Message
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DateTime.Parse`

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

then

```
 && DateTime.ParseExact(a.clieGenDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider) >= todate
```

Now the good question is : why  do you store dates as varchar ?

You probably know that using `.AsEnumerable()`, you will retrieve all your datas before applying the where clause ?

You could at least do

```
from a in Context.CliientDetails.Where(c => c.cliUserName == SalesEmal).AsEnumerable()
...
```